# Computation integral with complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

> Compute $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial B_1(0)} \frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99}-2z^{81}+z^4-7}dz$$

Im clueless. I would use the residue theorem, but factorising the denominator is not an option, I proved with Rouche that all 99 singularities are inside $B_1(0)$. None of them is removable. The numerator looks suspicious, but I don't really know what to do with it: one idea would be to use the argument principle but the integrand is not in the wished form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since every singularity lies in $B_1(0)$, then$$\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99}-2z^{81}+z^4-7}\,\mathrm dz$$is independent of the choice of $R$, as long as $R\geqslant1$. And\begin{multline}\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99}-2z^{81}+z^4-7}-\frac6{23z}\,\mathrm dz=\\=\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{6 \left(2 z^{81}-z^4+7\right)}{23\left(23 z^{100}-2z^{82}+z^5-7z\right)}\,\mathrm dz=0\end{multline}So,$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99}-2z^{81}+z^4-7}\,\mathrm dz=\frac6{23}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the numerator and denominator's powers are off by $1$ ($98$ vs $99$) is very suggestive of using the change of variables $z=\frac{1}{\zeta}$. This is further reinforced by the fact that all the poles lie inside $|z|=1$. If you make this change of variables then (be careful with orientation of the curve)
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,dz&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=1}f\left(\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta^2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{6\zeta}{23-2\zeta^{18}+\zeta^{95}-7\zeta^{99}}\cdot\frac{-d\zeta}{\zeta^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{6}{23-2\zeta^{18}+\zeta^{95}-7\zeta^{99}}\cdot\frac{1}{\zeta}\,d\zeta
\end{align}
Now by Rouche's theorem, you can once again verify (compare with the constant function $23$) that the denominator has no zeros inside $|\zeta|<1$. Hence, the pole is only at $\zeta=0$ with a residue of $\frac{6}{23}$.

Comment: (this is also a useful trick for when you're dealing with rational functions where denominator has degree relatively small, such as $4$-$6$, where it seems like a reasonable number of poles to deal with so one might be willing to use the usual residue theorem. However, by changing to "coordinates about the point at infinity", one can sometimes reduce the number of poles, so that *now* applying the residue theorem greatly simplifies calculations).